# Как изменить фон основного и дочернего окна по нажатию на элемент QListWidget

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qss

Я хотел сделать так, чтобы при нажатии `item 0` в `listwidget` фон **`двух`** окон менялся на красный. Если же потом кликнуть на `item 0`  фон обратно должен стать белым и после этого еще нажать, то он красным не станет.

Почему не меняется фон второго окна? Я хочу сделать так, что при нажатии `Red background` в `listwidget` фон обоих окон менялся, но сейчас он почему-то не меняется. Также после клика уже на `White background` фон менялся на белый обратно на обеих окнах и если еще раз нажать, то он менялся на красный!

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *

class Ui_MainWindow2(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(251, 192)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 140, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.label_1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 251, 191))
        self.label_1.setText("")
        self.label_1.setObjectName("label_1")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Back"))


class ExampleApp2(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow2):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)        

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.myclose)

    def myclose(self):
        self.close()


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(251, 191)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.listWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.listWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 256, 191))
        self.listWidget.setObjectName("listWidget")
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(21)
        item.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 170, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.listWidget.raise_()
        self.pushButton.raise_()
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Open Window"))

class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.listWidget.insertItem(0, "Red background")
        self.listWidget.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.listWidget.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.listWidget.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.listWidget.setFont (QFont ("Helvetica", 20)); 
        self.listWidget.setStyleSheet("QListWidget::item:hover {background: rgba(158, 158, 158, 40);}\n"
"QListWidget::item:selected {background: transparent;}\n"
"QListWidget::item:selected {color: black;}\n"
"")

        self.listWidget.itemClicked.connect(self.openWindow)       

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.click)

    def click(self):
        self.exampleApp_2 = ExampleApp2(self)
        self.exampleApp_2.show()


    def openWindow(self, item):                                  
        if item.text() == "Red background":                 
            self.exampleApp_2 = ExampleApp2(self) 
            self.listWidget.removeItemWidget(item)
            self.listWidget.takeItem(0)
            self.listWidget.setCurrentRow(0)
            self.listWidget.insertItem(0, "White background")
            self.listWidget.setStyleSheet("background-color: red;")
            self.exampleApp_2.label_1.setStyleSheet("background-color: red;")            
        else:
            self.listWidget.setStyleSheet("background-color: white;")
            self.exampleApp_2.label_1.setStyleSheet("background-color: white;")

if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ExampleApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

В чем же ошибка?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я отметит для вас строки, которые отредактировал.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *

class Ui_MainWindow2(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(850, 270, 251, 192)) #resize(251, 192)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
#        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 140, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton_1")
        self.label_1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 251, 191))
        self.label_1.setText("12312231223")
        self.label_1.setObjectName("label_1")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Back"))


class ExampleApp2(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow2):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)  

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.myclose)

    def myclose(self):
        self.hide()            #close()


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(251, 191)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.listWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.listWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 256, 191))
        self.listWidget.setObjectName("listWidget")
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(21)
        item.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 170, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.listWidget.raise_()
        self.pushButton.raise_()
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Open Window"))


class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.listWidget.insertItem(0, "Red background")
        self.listWidget.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.listWidget.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.listWidget.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.listWidget.setFont (QFont ("Helvetica", 20)); 
        self.listWidget.setStyleSheet("QListWidget::item:hover {background: rgba(158, 158, 158, 40);}\n"
"QListWidget::item:selected {background: transparent;}\n"
"QListWidget::item:selected {color: black;}\n"
"")

        self.listWidget.itemClicked.connect(self.openWindow)       
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.click)

        self.exampleApp_2 = ExampleApp2(self)                               # +++ 

    def click(self):
#        self.exampleApp_2 = ExampleApp2(self)
        self.exampleApp_2.show()

    def openWindow(self, item):
        if item.text() == "Red background":                 
#            self.exampleApp_2 = ExampleApp2(self) 
            self.listWidget.removeItemWidget(item)
            self.listWidget.takeItem(0)
            self.listWidget.setCurrentRow(0)
            self.listWidget.insertItem(0, "White background")
            self.listWidget.setStyleSheet("background-color: red;")
            self.exampleApp_2.label_1.setStyleSheet("background-color: red;")            
        else:
            self.listWidget.setStyleSheet("background-color: white;")
            self.exampleApp_2.label_1.setStyleSheet("background-color: white;")

            item.setText("Red background")                                      # +++


if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ExampleApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]